# Eloquent on Laravel 8 GROUP BY return each row instead of one of each type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to return data from a table, grouping the rows either by `company_id` or `worker_id` if `company_id` `is null` filtering by `member_id`

My table looks like this:

| id | library_id | member_id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | worker_id | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 1 |  |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 7 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 1 |  |
| 8 | 8 | 2 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2022-01-31 15:02:32 |  | 2 |  |

I created a function in my repository that looks like this:

```php
return Table::select('company_id', 'worker_id', 'created_at')
    ->where('member_id', $memberId)
    ->groupBy('company_id', 'worker_id', 'created_at')
    ->get();
```

I expected to get something like:

| created_at | worker_id | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 1 |  |
| 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-31 15:02:32 | 2 |  |

but I'm getting every row in the table filtered by the `member_id`

I've tried using `->distinct()` but got no lucky. Can someone help me?

Comment: what type you have no column type. WHERE clause will **remove** all row that have member_id  1 before grouping. Last your result has member_id 1 but the data hasn't

Comment: so I should group by only one column and maybe do a second query? I've tried doing so by company_id, but got 2 rows per company, if I could get only one, and discarding the info in the worker_id column would work too

Comment: that is strange this should work like a charm https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91f711a29291e4bad430e7845add2bc2  , maybe an old version of the databse?

Comment: i'm using the latest version of mysql, also laravel. I think that the query is validating the whole row. I'll try to use only the 'company_id' column and get the row with a 'first()'

Comment: get the raw statement and test it against the server or the dbfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the group by function is used in conjunction with functions to obtain some statistical data. There is no such thing in your request, try adding for example something like count(id) and you will see how the server response changes. In addition, grouping is characterized by the use of the function having
Do you really need grouping? Perhaps it is enough for you to get the first found row according to your filter? such as

```
return Table::select('company_id', 'worker_id', 'created_at')
    ->where('member_id', $memberId)->first();
```